# Wordpress custom search page for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type `recipes` which displays a paged list of recipes on the site using the `archive-recipes.php` template.

I need to be able to search through these recipes using the search form at the top of the page:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="searchbox" action="/recipes/">
    <input type="text" class="textbox strong" name="s" id="s" value="" placeholder="Search..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="recipes" />                     
    <button type="submit" class="button icon"></button>
</form>
```

Is it possible to return to this recipe listing page once the search has been performed and display the results in the same style as the listings?

I can't seem to find anything that will enable me to create a custom search page for custom post types.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the 'template_include' filter.

e.g. in your functions file.

```
function template_chooser($template)
{
  global $wp_query;
  $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
  if( $wp_query->is_search && $post_type == 'recipes' )
  {
    return locate_template('archive-recipes.php');
  }
  return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'template_chooser');
```

This should check for a search on the 'recipes' custom post type and use your archive page template for the results.

Comment: Thanks @noisymask. Looks like it should work like I need however when debugging **$wp_query** I noticed that the sql request contains a search for all the post types and not just 'recipes'. Any ideas?

Comment: nvm, the WP Roots framework i'm using was messing up the re-writes. thanks again.

Comment: The above solution works well; however I found that `get_query_var('post_type')` returned an array of all registered post types. Instead I'd use `$post_type = get_post_type();`. Also, to save some conditional checking for multiple post types: `return locate_template('archive-' . $post_type . '.php');`